# Route local port from Raspbian to another machine (port tunneling)

Tags: networking, raspbian

I want to route incoming tcp traffic on port 5555 on a Raspberry with Raspbian to another machine and port within the same local network, and make it persistent to reboots.

## Context

The objective is that if I access the service on 5555 on localhost, it will load a different port on the remote machine. The ultimate goal is to forward port 53 (DNS) into another machine (non-53 port), but in the meantime, I am testing with http: `https://localhost:5555`, it should load `https://192.168.250.250:9999` where 192.168.250.250 is a remote machine within my local network (accessible to all local network, `ping 192.168.250.250` works).

## What I've tried

There's a lot of resources on networking like this. Most rely on IP Forwarding on the router, which won't work in my case as I am trying to redirect ports within hosts in my localhost accessing the machines directly. The others, for port tunnelling, all use the methods below:

### iptables

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --sport 5555 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.250.250 --dport 9999`

This didn't work. I tried a few variations, including:

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --sport 5555 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.250.250:9999`

This didn't work, despite the rule getting registered:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:5555 dpt:9999 to:192.168.250.250

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I have also installed `iptables-persistent` to make it persistent, but it just doesn't redirect in the first place.

I have also tried a variant of the command since I think I may have misunderstood the "source" port as being the destination:

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.250.250:9999 --dport 5555`

After any of these changes, I always run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent
sudo netfilter-persistent save
sudo netfilter-persistent restart
```

To make sure the rules are permanently applied. I have also tried [this tutorial](http://www.intellamech.com/RaspberryPi-projects/rpi_iptables.html) to load the configuration on reboot. Nonetheless, again, this just doesn't forward, the permanent side of it is unclear and secondary at this stage.

### socat

`socat tcp-listen:5555,reuseaddr,fork tcp:192.168.250.250:9999`

This works fine. However, it's not persistent. As soon as I cntrl+c the terminal, it stops redirecting.

### nc

`sudo nc -l -p 5555 -c 'nc 192.168.250.250 9999'`
and
`sudo nc -l -p 5555 192.168.250.250 9999`

Neither work. The first one throws errors (-c not existing). The latter doesn't do anything.

Comment: I am considering whether my command is actually incorrect and should be `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.250.250:9999 --dport 5555`

Comment: Oh, yes...  I only seen this now  - `tcp spt:5555` this is wrong. Use the command from above & make sure you're not matching on sport

Comment: Yes. Working with that one now and it works, except response is not arriving. Created a new question to follow up on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65868741/response-to-ip-forwarded-port-not-coming-back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The up tables solution should work. However, you must check your ipv4 forwarding and enable it (most linux distros will have this as not enabled/allowed) and this is likely to be your problem.

Check this

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
0
```

0 means ip_forwarding is not allowed and the kernel will not perform it.

Either do

```
$ echo 1> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

or use sysctl

```
$ sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Danail. You're right on the forwarding being disabled. The first command requires a space after the 1 to work, and double root which may confuse people unless indicating `sudo su -` first. In the second command, you have an extra spacing around the `=` sign. If you could edit for others, it'd be great :) Despite this, once changed to value 1, it still doesn't forward :(

Comment: I have used a mobile device last night so the formatting isn't great. Anyway, there are a few things you must consider - what happens when the traffic reaches 192.168.250.250? Will this traffic be returned via this machine (where you setup iptables) or will it use it's default gateway (to route back to the source). Also, check & make sure the forwarding is enabled for all interfaces. Start a tcpdump on 192.168.250.250 & see if traffic arrives there.

Comment: No worries for the format, I appreciate it. I thought it was a good response and hence why I suggested the fixes so it's better for the future. You're right, the port forwarding seems to be working. The tcdump shows traffic. The routes look good for both IP ranges (the device who requested and the device which forwarded) on the "--to-destination" machine. However, I am guessing that the IP routing has something to do with it.

Comment: I think I am gonna mark your answer as valid since it solves the port redirect issue, and open a new one to troubleshoot why the response is not going back. Thanks. I would still encourage to change the format so other less experienced people do not struggle with the changes :) Thanks!